# Max Unix timestamp search for spesifit time in php

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a SQL list where I put time using timestamp.
My time column like this timestamp store and human time only for understand

```
[1532422822] => 24-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532422942] => 24-07-2018 11:02 AM
[1532509222] => 25-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532509282] => 25-07-2018 11:01 AM
[1532595622] => 26-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532595802] => 26-07-2018 11:03 AM
[1532682022] => 27-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532682202] => 27-07-2018 11:03 AM
[1532768422] => 28-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532768602] => 28-07-2018 11:03 AM
[1532854822] => 29-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532854942] => 29-07-2018 11:02 AM
[1532941222] => 30-07-2018 11:00 AM
[1532941402] => 30-07-2018 11:03 AM
```

Now I need to find max 11:00 AM or 11:02 AM. Is it possible using MySQL query or PHP code?

Comment: To clarify; You need to select or filter everything before 11:00AM for each day? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: No. I just need max 11:00AM.
For this collection my output will be "1532941222"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not possible. Because if you want to query for that, you just need to do that for a specific date.